# Pattern matching for an algebraic equation

Tags: pattern-matching

I have question related to pattern matching of a complex algebraic equations. If I am about to extract certain terms from an algebraic expressions that contains mixture of terms $\nabla_\gamma _{\alpha\beta}$ and $_{\alpha\beta}$ as in:

$=⋯\times\nabla_\gamma _{\alpha\beta}+⋯\times _{\alpha\beta},$

and in code as

```
 = -(I*Subscript[A, 2, 1]*Subscript[f, 1, 2]*(Cross[v, B] +   El)) + 
   I*Subscript[A, 1, 2]*Subscript[f, 2, 1]*(Cross[v, B] + El) - 
   (1/2)*Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 2], k]*
  Cross[-2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1], B] - 
   (1/2)*Grad[Subscript[f, 2, 1], k]*
  Cross[2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2], B] - 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 1, 2]*Subscript[f, 1, 1]*
  Cross[-2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1], B] + 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 2, 1]*Subscript[f, 1, 1]*
  Cross[2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2], B] + 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 1, 1]*Subscript[f, 1, 2]*
  Cross[-2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1], B] - 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 2, 2]*Subscript[f, 1, 2]*
  Cross[-2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1], B] - 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 1, 1]*Subscript[f, 2, 1]*
  Cross[2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2], B] + 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 2, 2]*Subscript[f, 2, 1]*
  Cross[2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2], B] + 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 1, 2]*Subscript[f, 2, 2]*
  Cross[-2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1], B] - 
   (1/2)*I*Subscript[A, 2, 1]*Subscript[f, 2, 2]*
  Cross[2*I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2], B] + 
   I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 1, 2]*Grad[Subscript[f, 2, 1], r] - 
   I*\[Epsilon]*Subscript[A, 2, 1]*Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 2], r] + 
   Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k]*(-(Cross[v, B] + El)) + 
 v*Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], r] + 
   Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], t]
```

how can I use multiple patterns to do the job. I tired the following two patterns to extract diagonal terms for instance

```
pat1 = h_*Grad[Subscript[f, x_, y_] /; x != y, _];
pat2 = h_*(Subscript[f, x_, y_] /; x != y);
```

and they work fine if I use DeleteCases twice on the original expression

```
expr1=Plus @@ Flatten@DeleteCases[expr, pat1, All];
expr2=Plus @@ Flatten@DeleteCases[expr1, pat2, All];
Print[expr2]
```

But is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please include code for `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the doubled `DeleteCases` by specifying the two
patterns as `Alternatives`. Also, `Flatten` and `All` are not needed in the given case.

```
Plus @@ DeleteCases[expr, pat1 | pat2]

result == expr2
```

True

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use of derivatives with patterns don't work, because the patterns are evaluated and produce 0 if the expression is not visibly dependent on the variable.

Use HoldPattern as a wrapper e.g

```
 expr /.{ HoldPattern[ Grad[a_,{t__}] :> Subscript[\[Nabla],t ] . a

 Cases[expr,HoldPattern[ D[Subscript[_,_,_],t__]]
```

Another way is the use of Wrapper Inactive[Grad] on the operators in the formula, that is semantically identical but does nothing on evaluation.

More than one pattern can be supplied by Alternatives  (_ | _ |...)

```
  Select[expr, (MatchQ[#,  pat1 | pt2]&)]
```

Comment: Your `Select` doesn't give the expected result - even after replacing `pt2`with `pat2`

Comment: As far as I see the original expression evaluates all derivatives to zero.

Comment: @Ronald F In the original expression the function is $f (r,k,t)$ so the derivatives survive. None of this solutions provide my desired result which must have terms that are all diagonal in $f$.

Comment: I have a suspicion that utilizing the Alternatives (_|_|...) approach in this scenario will yield the correct answer. I am seeking a method to combine both the pattern (pat1 and pat2) with boolean logic using **and**. Is there a way to integrate the pattern with the **and** operator?